# How to set thumbnail on YouTube thumbnail view

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, youtube-api

I wanna know that How to set YouTube thumbnailView on recyclerview using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter? IDs of the videos comes from the firebase database

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code:

```
YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView = (YouTubeThumbnailView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_thumbnail);
    youTubeThumbnailView.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, final YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {
        youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(videoId);
        youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {
            youTubeThumbnailLoader.release();
        }

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {

        }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: No I did it before u gave yours

Comment: @Umesh then please post your code and accept it as an answer.